# VLC video player doesn't work in C# win form on Client

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, activex, vlc

I'm using the COM component VLC Active X V2 in my C# Windows Form for playing a web .flv file.

On my Project Building PC (With Win8, Visual Studio 2012, VS 2015 and VLC 2.2.1) it works fine running the Release. But I want to place it on a simple pc (with Win7 and VLC 2.2.1) but it doesn't work inside my C# Windows form running the Release.

I get the following error: (Sorry for bad translate..)

> Can file or assembly AxInterop,AXVLC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null or one of the independents not load. 
>   System can't find the file.

I tested VLC Active X plugin in Internet Explorer and works fine.
I can't find anything about it, even not at the website of VideoLan.org

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is what I did;
It seem that Vlc 2.2.1 has some problems, so you need to download vlc 2.2.2 version, I downloaded the zipped file because the installer failed to instal on my PC and the register it with regserv32.
 this should sort out your problem if you haven't found any solution.
Thanks